# Entering default text for password field

Tags: javascript, forms

Is there a way to enter a default text to a password field?

Basically I have a password field that is supposed to mask someone's id but before the user enteres the id, I want the field's value to show 'Enter your ID here'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused. There are two fields, one for ID and one for password? Or there's just one field which is actually the password but it says to "enter your ID here" until they start typing, and then it's masked with the usual bullets?

Comment: There is only 1 password field but it is not really for password, rather for masking id. However, before the id is entered, I want the field to say 'enter your id here'. WHen the user enters the id, the id will be masked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use plain javascript, you could do:

**HTML**

```
<label for="placeholder">Password:</label>
<input type="text" id="placeholder" value="Enter password here" onFocus="setPass();"/>
<input type="password" id="password" value="" onBlur="checkPass();" style="display: none;"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function setPass() {
    document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('password').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('password').focus();
}
function checkPass() {
    if (document.getElementById('password').value.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('password').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4NN/1/

Answer (score 1):

At this moment if you want to support all types of browsers (that have enabled JavaScript), you should use JavaScript. I believe there a some scripts you could use, but writing one yourself is a good option too of course. In an earlier stage I have written a script myself to do this where I changed the TYPE field of the input to 'text' when no password was entered. When a user focused on the password field, the type was changed back to 'password'.

Mind Internet Explorer: I believe 7 and below do not allow you to change the type of the field. But any other decent browser does.

If your requirement is that browsers that support at least HTML 5 should be able to use it, have a look at **HTML 5 placeholders**. I think it does exactly what you want as well.

[Check this link for more info](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html), it has some info on placeholders as well. Have fun! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="Enter your ID here"
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your ID here') this.value = ''"
    onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Enter your ID here'"
/>
```

Comment: He was talking about a password field, not a Text field ;)